# jQuery mousedown stopping click? (in rails 3 environment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-events

I have a link in rails that's a remote link (i.e. submits through ajax)

The link would be like so:

```
<a href="#myurl" data-remote="true">
<div class="switchIt switchOn">my linked item</div>
</a>
```

When the link is clicked - nothing on the page happens, and that's the success.

So I've added an effect on `.mousedown`, for the div's style to change (a simple `.removeClass` and `.addClass`). I need to it be mousedown, rather than click (which is more like mouseup) because of the effect I'm trying to achieve.

The problem I'm running into now, is that after clicking the div, the link no longer "submits" the url at all. Its as if mousedown has blocked it.

I could make the link remote through a jQuery ajax call and fix this nonsense - but I'd rather let rails handle it as it has been, and does elsewhere in my site.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Updated with script...:

```
$('body').delegate('.switchIt', 'mousedown', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('switchOn');
   $(this).toggleClass('switchOff');
});
```

Comment: should we guess what is the script?

Comment: toggling both classes will remove both simultaneously, and add both simultaneously..since they both exist on page load. Nothing in code shown would block a click

Comment: You can also use rails ERB helpers to keep it railsy:
<%= link_to "your_url_path" do %>
  <div class="switchIt switchOn">my linked item</div>
<% end %>

Comment: @Galaxy thats how it is in my code - buy I figured showing the plain HTML might help people looking from a non-rails perspective